# Get File Author of Word Document, VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

my Question is how to get a the author name of a specific Word Document.

My function is:

```
Public Function GetFileOwner(pFile As String) As String

GetFileOwner = pFile.Owner

End Function
```

i get here about 100 documents through, i already tried `.BuiltInDocmementProperties.`, but this was much too slow...

also the Shell.Application function doesn't work for me, because this only works with all files in a folder, but i need it for specific Files..

Does somebody know a other faster solution? And is there also a way for PDF - documents?

Comment: Could you please also post the codes for `.BuiltInDocmementProperties` and       `Shell.Application` you already tried, and output or errors. If you want to get an answer for PDF also, IMO better you to add it to title, and both add to tags.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this quite easily in .NET, so I wrote a small dll with unmanaged exports:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using RGiesecke.DllExport;
using System.IO.Compression;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace DocxProperties
{
    public class DocxPropertyGetter
    {
        [DllExport(nameof(GetDocxProp), CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.AnsiBStr)]
        public static string GetDocxProp([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.AnsiBStr)] string wordPath, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.AnsiBStr)] string propName)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var fileStream = File.Open(wordPath, FileMode.Open))
                using (var parentArchive = new ZipArchive(fileStream))
                {
                    return GetPropName(parentArchive, propName);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return ex.ToString();
            }
        }

        private static string GetPropName(ZipArchive parentArchive, string propName)
        {
            var core = parentArchive.Entries.FirstOrDefault(e => e.FullName == "docProps/core.xml");

            using (var coreStream = core.Open())
            {
                var doc = XDocument.Load(coreStream);

                foreach (var descendant in doc.Descendants())
                {
                    if (descendant.Name.LocalName.Equals(propName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                    {
                        return descendant.Value;
                    }
                }
            }

            return string.Empty;
        }

    }
}
```

The code is slightly more verbose than necessary in order to avoid some curious errors in RGiesecke.DllExport if I used .FirstOrDefault() or .GetEntry();

This DLL can in turn be called from VBA like this:

```
Option Explicit

#If Win64 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function LoadLibraryA Lib "kernel32" (ByVal lpLibFileName As String) As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetDocxProp Lib "DocxProperties64.dll" (ByVal wordPath As String, ByVal propName As String) As String
#Else
    Private Declare Function LoadLibraryA Lib "kernel32" (ByVal lpLibFileName As String) As Long
    Private Declare Function GetDocxProp Lib "DocxProperties64.dll" (ByVal wordPath As String, ByVal propName As String) As String
#End If

Sub TestAuthorName()
    Dim dllPath As String

    #If Win64 Then
        dllPath = "DocxProperties64.dll"
    #Else
        dllPath = "DocxProperties32.dll"
    #End If

    Call LoadLibrary(dllPath)

    Debug.Print GetDocxProp(ThisWorkbook.path & "\EmptyDoc.docx", "creator")

End Sub

Private Function LoadLibrary(dllName As String) As Long
    Dim path As String
    path = ThisWorkbook.path & "\" & dllName
    LoadLibrary = LoadLibraryA(path)
End Function
```

Sorry if I got the Declares wrong for 32 bit... I don't have any 32 version of MS Office to test with.